# I want to pass a string response from a previous API call to a new API call

Tags: php, laravel

I have an API service that requires an encrypted string to be sent as a payload to their service and you in turn get an encrypted string response to be decrypted by another service. The challenge is that I get a string lije this `Kcc6rcdO41XJ9ZNavb6AeJXwM0pxEfRLUipPpIM3ayRrLT2tWp4xD/0B28/W09siYJ2dVOZGOA1jUSMZLxXdFZimJHrzxZKuiSvV+ECPY4CyyTi3Sp1CvKuNLERFu4iQ8knlq00Fj2nL8qVyu19WOg==` as a response but I cannot pass the string as a payload to the decryption endpoint as it always return null.
This is my code

```
$response2 = Http::withHeaders($headers2)->post($url2, $fields2);
$json = json_decode($response2);
 $fields3 = [
          "value" => json_decode($json)
        ];

 $response3 = Http::withHeaders($headers)->post($url3, $fields3);
```

My `$response2 = Kcc6rcdO41XJ9ZNavb6AeJXwM0pxEfRLUipPpIM3ayRrLT2tWp4xD/0B28/W09siYJ2dVOZGOA1jUSMZLxXdFZimJHrzxZKuiSvV+ECPY4CyyTi3Sp1CvKuNLERFu4iQ8knlq00Fj2nL8qVyu19WOg==` but it doesn`t end up passing into the new endpoint.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by accessing the string using `body()`

`$json = $response2->body();`